# nodejs equivalent of this .htaccess

Tags: node.js, .htaccess

Is it possible to build a code like this in `node.js`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI}! / (View) / [NC]
     RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F
     RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Index.html [L, QSA]

</IfModule>
```

url display a route is not "view" and also the file does not exist then write `index.html`.

using something like `express` or `connect`

UPDATE: I need a regular expression for `!/(view)/` in route for `express` in `node.js`.

Comment: How does htaccess know that a route is a view? Does it check if it ends with .html?

Comment: I understand that "view" is the directory name, uri request applies regular expression string in the url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final structure is:

```
var express = require('express'), url = require('url');

var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
    next();
});
app.configure(function() {
    var pub_dir = __dirname + '/public';
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
    app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(pub_dir));
    app.use(app.router);
});
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    if (req.xhr) {
        var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        res.sendfile('index.html', {root: __dirname + '/public' + pathname});
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Thanks everyone.
PD: Render html with module ejs

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried:

1. Serve statics
2. Catch /view URL
3. Catch everything else

   ```
   app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); // Catch static files
     app.use(app.routes);
   });

   // Catch /view and do whatever you like
   app.all('/view', function(req, res) {

   });

   // Catch everything else and redirect to /index.html
   // Of course you could send the file's content with fs.readFile to avoid
   // using redirects
   app.all('*', function(req, res) { 
     res.redirect('/index.html'); 
   });
   ```

OR

1. Serve statics
2. Check if URL is /view

   ```
   app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); // Catch static files
     app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       if (req.url == '/view') {
         next();
       } else {
         res.redirect('/index.html');
       }
     });
   });
   ```

OR

1. Catch statics as usual
2. Catch NOT /view

   ```
   app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); // Catch static files
     app.use(app.routes);
   });

   app.get(/^(?!\/view$).*$/, function(req, res) {
     res.redirect('/index.html');
   });
   ```

Comment: can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the express Middleware urlrewrite.

If you don't handle rewrites on a reverse proxy for example and if using express and want regex support for flexibility use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite