# how to change hash to slash in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('ngView', ['ngRoute'],
    function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/test',
        {
          template: '{{}}',
          controller: function(){
            console.log('controller');
            $('div').first().html('<b>OK</b>');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  );
  </script>
```

This is all my angular code. In URL, i can access test by

```
file:///Users/tom/Documents/Projects/a4/index2.html#/test
file:///Users/tom/Documents/Projects/a4/index2.html#test
```

Both of the above two ways work.

But when I change `#/test to /test`, it doesn't work.

How do I configure Angularjs to only use `'/'` in URL path?

Comment: You need to enable HTML5 model in config state `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. Please see the guide here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Comment: Thanks! I checked this HTML5 question before asking this question, but didn't think it is related to my situation.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work for me... strange...

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are working locally, you need a server to work with `html5Mode`, after enabling it you need to define an `.htaccess` or a `virtual host` on the server take a look at this question [AngularJS: can't get html5 mode urls with ui-route $state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444072/angularjs-cant-get-html5-mode-urls-with-ui-route-state)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am using nodejs, and I didn't find any .htaccess in the project folder. Does this solution still apply to nodejs? HTML5 is a browser side technology, why do i need to configure server?

Comment: I put the project files on a local nodejs server running express4 MVC framework. Here is the access URL: http://localhost:3000/a4/test . It still won't work. (no .htaccess file) If you are familar with nodejs server, can you please tell me what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I never had any experience with nodejs advanced configurations but maybe you could use something from these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199095/nodejs-equivalent-of-this-htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777967/using-angularjs-html5mode-with-nodejs-and-express http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222252/how-to-use-angularjs-routes-with-express-node-js-when-a-new-page-is-requested