# .htaccess file won't work on my node.js app

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file located in the root directory of my node.js app:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

My website runs at www.mywebsite.com. When a form is submitted, the page is redirected to a success page:

```
res.redirect("/success.html");
```

The problem is, my .htaccess file isn't working properly. I am redirected to www.mywebsite.com/success.html, instead of www.mywebsite.com/success.

I have tried changing my node.js script to:

```
res.redirect("/success");
```

But then I get an error page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .htaccess only work for apache server, not for node

Comment: So, is there a workaround/other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is only for Apache servers, but you can try something like this:

[nodejs equivalent of this .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199095/nodejs-equivalent-of-this-htaccess)