# Next.js index route returns 404

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express, next.js

I got a problem to get my nextjs app running on my production server. 
I portforward it via htaccess by following code:

`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:1338/$1`

Every route is working perfectly: /blog,/blog/:id, /about etc.
Just "/" is not working when rendered from serverside. I can navigate to it after loading another route without any problem. 
I can also call it by */index* but not with *mydomain.tld*

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue happens when Apache tries to pass an index.html file to the next router which returns an error.

Adding `DirectoryIndex disabled` to .htaccess file solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect using Apache Module but you seem to be using Node.js

Try looking at 
[nodejs equivalent of this .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199095/nodejs-equivalent-of-this-htaccess)

Comment: Thats true, because there is a apache running on the server and i have to make him redirect to the right port on which the express app is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete `.htaccess` for implementing a Node.js application with an Apache redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Need to disable DirectoryIndex to avoid rewriting directory URL to index.html
DirectoryIndex disabled

# Redirect home page request to the NextJS server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4002/ [P,L]

# Redirect all other requests to the NextJS server with the URI appended
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4002/$1 [P,L]
```